# Reverse engineer a sample value from a CDF

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics

The image below shows the cumulative distribution of a normal distribution with mean = 4 and standard deviation = 1. Notice that if you have a value with a rank of 0.8 (meaning it would be 80th item from the bottom in a sorted list of 100 items) you could get the corresponding value from the CDF of a normal distribution of any mean/sd (if you knew how to do it). I'll bet there is a nice way to do this. I can only think of overly complicated, never do it what way! ways.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean [`InverseCDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseCDF.html)?

Comment: Is it that easy?  I'll  check.  Yes! It's that easy.  If you put your comment as an answer and I'll  accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either [`InverseCDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseCDF.html) or [`Quantile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quantile.html) may be used to find the population/data cutoffs (or quantiles) corresponding to given cdf level.  The functions are [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html), too.

Both

```
 InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[4, 1], Range[0.1, 0.9, 0.1]]
```

and

```
 Quantile[NormalDistribution[4, 1], Range[0.1, 0.9, 0.1]]
```

yield the deciles for the example normal distribution.

```
(* {2.71845, 3.15838, 3.4756, 3.74665, 4., 4.25335, 4.5244, 4.84162, 5.28155} *)
```